# How to set the FSM configuaration for Textricator PDF OCR reader?

Tags: itext, ocr, pdfbox, text-extraction

I'm trying to use the PDF document parser called [Textricator](https://github.com/measuresforjustice/textricator). It can use 3 different methods for parsing a PDF with some common OCR libraries. (*itext5, itext7, pdfbox*) The available methods are: `text`, `table` and `form`. *Text* for normal raw OCR recognition, *table* to read out structured table data, and *form* for parsing less structured forms, using a *Finite State Machine* (FSM).

However, I am not able to use the *form* parser. Perhaps I simply don't understand how to organize the many configuration states. The documentation is lacking a simple form example, and someone recently posted an [attempt to read a very basic table](https://github.com/measuresforjustice/textricator/issues/19) using the *`form`* method, but was not able to. I also gave it a shot, but without any success.

Q: **Can someone help me configure the state machine in the YML file?**
(This is used to parse the demo file from one of that repo's *issues*, and shown in the copied screenshot below.)

---

[image]

---

The YML configuration file.

```yaml
extractor: "pdf.pdfbox"

header:
  default: 100
footer:
   default: 600

maxRowDistance: 2

rootRecordType: item
recordTypes:
  item:
    label: "item"
    valueTypes:
      - item
      - date
      - description
      - order_number
      - quantity
      - price

valueTypes:
  item:
    label: "Item"
  date:
    label: "Date"
  description:
    label: "Description"
  order_number:
    label: "OrderNo"
  quantity:
    label: "Qty"
  price:
    label: "Price"
 
initialState: "INIT"

states:
  INIT:
    transitions:
      -
        condition: item
        nextState: item

  item:
    startRecord: true
    transitions:
      -
        condition: date
        nextState: date  

  date:
    include: true
    transitions:
      -
        condition: description
        nextState: description  

  description:
    include: true
    transitions:
      -
        condition: description
        nextState: description     
      -
        condition: order_number
        nextState: order_number
      -
        condition: quantity
        nextState: quantity

  order_number:
    include: true
    transitions:
      -
        condition: order_number
        nextState: order_number
      -
        condition: quantity
        nextState: quantity

  quantity:
    include: true
    transitions:
      -
        condition: price
        nextState: price

  price:
    include: true
    transitions:
      -
        condition: end
        nextState: end

  end:
    include: false
    transitions:
      -
        condition: any
        nextState: end

conditions:

  item:         '73 < ulx < 110 and text =~ /(\\d)*/'
  date:         '110 < ulx < 181 and text =~ /([0-9\-]*)/'
  description:  '193 < ulx < 366'
#  order_number: '12 <= uly_rel <= 16 and text =~ ^.+/((\d{6})\-)((\d{2}))/'
  order_number: '12 <= uly_rel <= 16 and text =~ ^.+((\d{6})\-)((\d{2}))'
  quantity:     '393 < ulx < 459'
  price:        '459 < ulx < 523'

  end:          'text =~ /(Footer)/'
  any: "1 = 1"
```

You may wonder why I am insisting in using the *form* processor for this simple example, but it is because in my real life document I will have a much more complex sub-structure of child items under the *Description* field. This can only (?) be processed efficiently by a state-machine, AFAIK.

But, maybe this is not the right tool for the job? So what other options are there?

---

**UPDATE:** (2021-05-18)

The author of *Textricate* has now bumped the libraries used, the documentation and corrected several working examples and user issues. Thanks to user *mweber* I now have a perfectly working parser and no longer need to use *awk* to [handle weird columns](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/647233/56324).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Textricator is kind of a hidden gem for pdf parsing imo, I'm happy to see someone using it and posted a config working with the sample document to the github issue:

```
extractor: "pdf.pdfbox"

header:
  default: 100
footer:
  default: 600

maxRowDistance: 2

rootRecordType: item
recordTypes:
  item:
    label: "item"
    valueTypes:
      - item
      - date
      - description
      - order_number
      - quantity
      - price

valueTypes:
  item:
    label: "Item"
  date:
    label: "Date"
  description:
    label: "Description"
  order_number:
    label: "OrderNo"
  quantity:
    label: "Qty"
  price:
    label: "Price"

initialState: "INIT"

states:
  INIT:
    include: false
    transitions:
      -
        condition: item
        nextState: item
      - condition: any
        nextState: INIT

  item:
    startRecord: true
    transitions:
      -
        condition: date
        nextState: date  

  date:
    include: true
    transitions:
      -
        condition: description
        nextState: description  

  description:
    include: true
    transitions:
      -
        condition: description
        nextState: description     
      -
        condition: order_number
        nextState: order_number
      -
        condition: quantity
        nextState: quantity
      -
        condition: item
        nextState: item

  order_number:
    include: true
    transitions:
      -
        condition: order_number
        nextState: order_number
      -
        condition: quantity
        nextState: quantity

  quantity:
    include: true
    transitions:
      - 
        condition: price
        nextState: price

  price:
    include: true
    transitions:
      -
        condition: end
        nextState: end
      - 
        condition: description
        nextState: description
      -
        condition: item
        nextState: item

  end:
    include: false
    transitions:
      -
        condition: any
        nextState: end

conditions:

  item:         '73 < ulx < 110 and text =~ /(\\d)*/'
  date:         '110 < ulx < 181 and text =~ /([0-9\\-]*)/'
  description:  '193 < ulx < 366'
  order_number: '12 <= uly_rel <= 16 and text =~ /^.+(([0-9]{6})\\-)(([0-9]{2}))/'
  quantity:     '393 < ulx < 459'
  price:        '459 < ulx < 523'

  end:          'text =~ /(Footer)/'
  any: "1 = 1"
```

Comment: Great! SW author also added `filter: 'quantity > 0'` under the *recordTypes* (with 4-spaces indent) and `type: number` under *quantity* of *valueTypes*.